# How to use loadData to load NSData (o/p of UIImageJPEGRepresentation) into wkwebview?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, loaddata

As part of iOS9 we have the new method [loadData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/loadData:MIMEType:characterEncodingName:baseURL:)() introduced into WKWebView.

I have NSData object that is output of UIImageJPEGRepresentation that I want to render in a WKWebView. Prior to iOS9, in order to render image in wkwebview, I was:

- storing nsdata on the local file system as a .jpeg file
- create a nsurl with fileWithUrl init method
- Call wkwebview.loadRequest(url) where url is the nsurl created in previous step

I was hoping take advantage of the new iOS9 method where I can directly call the wkwebview.loadData(nsdata, MIMEType:"image", characterEncoding:"ASCII", baseURL: NSURL("random"))

I am not able to render the image using the above loadData call. Could be issue with the params I am passing for MIMEType, characterEncoding and baseUrl. Could not find any examples for this method call anywhere.

Notes:

- I am not sure what characterEncoding to use when rendering image
- The baseUrl cannot be nil and so initialized it to a random url

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Test", ofType: "jpg") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
            webView.loadData(data, MIMEType: "image/jpeg",
                characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: NSURL(string: "")!)
        }
    }
```

The `characterEncodingName` and `baseURL` look a bit odd but I doubt they are relevant for loading `image/jpeg` type data.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. This didnt work for me. webview loading errors out and displays the error handling message I have in my code

Comment: What is the error? I tried this code before I posted it.

Comment: Try adding @"UTF-8" in the characterEncodingName, and I think I've read somewhere that leaving the baseUrl blank is bad, so add [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] in the baseUrl parameter, this baseUrl parameter doesn't do anything, it's just a bad idea to leave it blank based on what I've read before

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late answer, we had similar issue in one of our projects, one way you can solve this is using html's power by embedding the content inside html.

```
func loadDataContent(data:Data,mimeType:String) {
    let urlStr = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"data:\(mimeType);base64,\(data.base64EncodedString())\"></iframe>"
    webBrowser?.loadHTMLString(urlStr, baseURL: nil)
}
```